# tooltip chartjs y-Axis value dropped feedback

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to add a feedback or message in the tooltip of chartjs when the value of the y-Axis which is an array of numbers drops. I am using the callbacks but did not come to a solution. Any help would be appreciative. Thank you!
There is my code

````
                        callbacks: {
                            beforeFooter: (e) => {
                                function bla(i: any, numberArray: any) {
                                numberArray = chart?.data.datasets[1].data;
                                for(i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i ++){
                                    if(numberArray[i +1 ] < numberArray[i]){
                                        return 'not so good'
                                    }
                                }
                                return 'good';
                                
                            }
                            return 'okay'
                        }
                        }
                    },```
````

Comment: Having a look to your code, I have the feeling that the result is before the footer you get always "okay", doesn't it?

Comment: @user2057925 yes this is the result i always get because the bla function will never be read

Comment: And the result is still not correct, for your stand point?

Comment: @user2057925 yeah its still not correct

Comment: can you create a sample to reproduce the issue and also what you want to reach (visually)?